# c# Auto generate relations on DataSet

Tags: c#, dataset, constraints, relationships

I have a task where I want to fill Dataset with multiple tables from database (MSSQL Server) and with their relationships.

And my question is: Is possible to auto generate relations between tables in dataset, if relations was set up already on database level? and if it is possible then how?

Comment: I think that is not possible. Because you are making separated select from the tables. 
You can use linq query(example) to get what you need from the tables after casting results into models.

Comment: I don't believe there is any option to "Auto detect" relationships in a SQL server database presumably for your XSD.